# choco assign int to IntVar

Tags: constraints, variable-assignment, modeling, solver, choco

For a variable array like

```
IntVar[][] array = VF.boolMatrix("example", 5, 10, solver);
```

what is the difference between

```
solver.post(ICF.arithm(array[i][j], "=", 0));
```

and

```
array[i][j] = VariableFactory.fixed(0, solver);
```

Is one superior to another in terms of eg. less space needed, faster solving, less backtracking?

Answer (score 0):

array[i][j] = VariableFactory.fixed(0, solver); is more efficient because the fixed view consumes less memory (not a huge difference for a BoolVar but true for an IntVar relying on a BitSet list domain implementation) and it avoids creating a useless constraint. These elements are quite minor but when multiplied by 10000, it can make a difference in runtime. Moreover, they are cached : if two views have the same value, only one new object will be created actually. However, the backtrack number will remain the same (unless the search heuristic is based on randomness or the number of constraints, etc.).

Best,

Jean-Guillaume Fages
https://www.cosling.com/